# TextBox's Text set through DataTrigger not updating the property value in Model

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

I am new to WPF and I want to clear a textBox's value if a check box is unchecked. I tried doing that through data triggers.

Below is the code:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Amount,Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <TextBox.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="TextBox.Text" Value="{x:Null}"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>  
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>
```

My checkbox's value is set in "IsSelected" property of My Model. Here, if the checkbox is unchecked, then the text's updated value, which is {x:Null} in this case, is not reflecting in "Amount" property of my Model. Because of this the text never seems to be changed on the UI. The "Amount" earlier set value is getting set again in the TextBox because of binding

Any help is appreciated. Let me know in case you need any more information or clarification
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In such cases I normally prefer ViewModel / Model doing the "clear" part of the functionality,

hence in your case I'd normally do something like:

```
public bool IsSelected {
  get {
    return _isSelected;
  }

  private set {
    if (value == _isSelected)
      return;

    RaisePropertyChanging(() => IsSelected);
    _isSelected = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsSelected);

    if (_isSelected == false)
      Amount = string.Empty
  }
}
```

That way the View does not hold responsibility for any logic and thus doesn't need the `DataTrigger` at all

**Update:**

The Problem with your code is when you set the `Text` with a Binding in the `TextBox` it takes precedence over the value you set in the `Style` for the Text property. You can check this by using this:

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
      <Setter Property="Text"
              Value="{Binding Path=Amount,
                              Mode=TwoWay}" />
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"
                      Value="false">
          <Setter Property="Text"
                  Value="{x:Null}" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

This will now clear the Text when the `CheckBox` is checked, however it will not be updating your Binding(`Amount`) since essentially your Binding is only active when the `CheckBox` is selected.

Comment: Hello Viv, Thanks for your time and answer. This approach of doing things will work in my case and I will try this. I also wanted to know like why the code in my case is not updating the property value even though it is binded in TwoWay Mode. Does the datatrigger not allow to update the binded property in this way? Thanks.

Comment: @DareToExplore no problem, I did update my answer with the reason for why your method is currently not working. Not got anything to do with the `DataTrigger`. It's just precedence and it cannot over-rule the precedence of the Binding which got set directly on the `TextBox`

Comment: I tried the updated code and what I conclude is if the check box is checked, then the value of the "Amount" property is shown in the textbox. when the checkbox is unchecked, then as per you said,the binding with the Amount property is not active. Hence, it is not updated in the Model. Correct me if I misunderstood any thing. Again, thnks for your time and answer. This is my first question in this forum and it helped. Keep up the good work. Thnks.

Comment: Aonther point I want to add here is like if we are using the auto generated enitites as our Model, then writing the code in the setter of the "IsSelected" property will be over-ridden if the entity is auto generated again. In this case we need to think of some other solution. Just FYI, since, I am not using auto generated entity for my this Model, this solution works. Thnks.

Comment: @DareToExplore Yes what you mentioned with the `DataTrigger` updates is correct and welcome to StackOverflow!!. As far as AutoGenerated Properties, If the property is auto generated it depends on what you get Auto-Generated, as in if the Autogenerated code raises a property changed event, then you will subscribe to that event. There we can check if `IsSelected` is false and update Amount. It boils down to what is actually available to work-with.