# Conditionally auto-click button in MVVM using xaml

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am writing an application based on MVVM architecture. The application has a Wizard like workflow. In couple of pages (views) in my application, I need a button to be auto-clicked when a certain condition is satisfied. The views are tied together using the root Wizard view model which has a ClickNextBtn command that is tied to the Next button in the root Wizard view. So, I need something like in the root Wizard view:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CanAutoClickNext}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="ClickBtn" Value="true" />
</DataTrigger>
```

The property in the above sample is meaningless, but hopefully it helps convey what I am trying to do.

The CanAutoClickNext bool property is available off of the Wizard view model.

On one of the views where I need the Next button auto-clicked, I tried passing the WizardViewModel as an argument to its corresponding view model's constructor when it is first instantiated in the root wizard view model, and then calling the ClickNextBtn off of it in a method therein later when the view is actually loaded. But that did not work, not surprisingly.

I know how to programmatically click a wpf button, but getting it all tied together in the framework I have is proving to a big challenge. Any feedback is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I ended up rewriting the UI design pattern (still MVVM) so that now instead of having to having to move to a next page automatically, the state within a page changes and a different set of controls become active. Users are then prompted to click next.

Comment: Umm... If it's MVVM, then it would probably be better to fire a message (aggregated event or whatever name you prefer) which the 'hosting' view model should handle. Something like `MoveNext`

Comment: It looks like your view is too "smart". In MVVM buttons are usually bound to commands. Clicking a button invokes a command. Why not just invoke a command directly in your ViewModel instead of that strange round-trip you are trying to implement?

Comment: @Den The button in the root wizard view I need to auto-click is already bound to a command in the root wizard view model. And users do need to manually click that button to proceed. However on couple of views, I need that button auto-clicked. That is the problem.

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor I am not sure how to bind the button to the proposed MoveNext message handler in the view model, but I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Like the comment's on your question stated, this should be a concern of the `ViewModel` to invoke the Click Handler.

How you could go about implementing this is very similar to something like this [Question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397570/textboxs-text-set-through-datatrigger-not-updating-the-property-value-in-model/16397762#comment23505564_16397762)

Now in MVVM, you should have your Button's connected to an `ICommand` in the ViewModel(If your using MVVM Light toolkit, it will be `RelayCommand`/`RelayCommand<T>`).

Now assuming this `ICommand` variable in your VM is called `NextButtonCommand`,

what you can do is

```
public bool CanAutoClickNext {
  get {
    return _canAutoClickNext;
  }

  private set {
    if (value == _canAutoClickNext)
      return;

    _canAutoClickNext = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => CanAutoClickNext);

    if (_canAutoClickNext)
      NextButtonCommand.Execute(null);
  }
}
```

with this, when your property in the VM `CanAutoClickNext` gets set to "True", the Execute function of the `ICommand` is automatically invoked by the VM. This seperates all the logic handling to the VM and keeps the View dumb as what is recommended by MVVM when it comes to application / business logic.

**Side Note**

The property `CanAutoClickNext` seems a waste if it's not being bound to anything from the View. If this is the case, I'd recommend just getting rid of that property and invoke the `ICommand.Execute(null)` from the place where the logic holds fit than use a property with INPC just for this case.

Answer (score 1):

I'll follow up from a different angle. Let's say you have any message bus ready (`IEventAggregator`, `IMessenger`, doesn't matter). I'll use the Caliburn.Micro's `IEventAggregator` along with the nomenclature 'cause that's what I'm most familiar with. Now you might have a very simple event:

```
public class MoveNext
{
}
```

Then your 'host' viewmodel of the wizard:

```
public class WizardHost : IHandle<MoveNext>
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator messageBus
    public WizardHost(IEventAggregator messageBus)
    {
        this.messageBus = messageBus;
        this.messageBus.Subscribe(this);
    }

    /here you might have the 'real' command method, e.g:
    public void GoToNextQuestion()
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    public void Handle(MoveNext message)
    {
        GoToNextQuestion();
    }
}

public class WizardPage 
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator messageBus;

    private bool shouldMoveToNext;
    public WizardPage(IEventAggregator messageBus)
    {
        this.messageBus = messageBus;

    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        //at some point, you might want to switch the flag or do whatever you need/want to do and:
        if(shouldMoveToNext)
            messageBus.Publish(new MoveNext());
    }
}
```

Now when you `DoStuff()` in your wizard page, you can publish the event and the 'host' page will react and flip the page.

That's of course all nice if you're using any MVVM framework that's out there. MVVM Light has the `Messenger`, Caliburn.Micro has - as you might have noticed - `IEventAggregator`.